# How do I set the file path to the current user?

Tags: python, directory, filepath

Right now for a directory path, I have:

```
os.chdir(r'C:\users\Ryan\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application')
```

How do I make it so that instead of "Ryan" it uses the username of the person using the script?

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at `expanduser` of [`os.path`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html):

> `os.path.expanduser(path)`
>
> On Unix and Windows, return the argument with an initial component of ~ or ~user replaced by that user‘s home directory.
>
> [..]
>
> On Windows, HOME and USERPROFILE will be used if set, otherwise a combination of HOMEPATH and HOMEDRIVE will be used. An initial ~user
>   is handled by stripping the last directory component from the created
>   user path derived above.
>
> If the expansion fails or if the path does not begin with a tilde, the path is returned unchanged.

Comment: +1 Good point. So the solution should be something like: `os.chdir(os.path.expanduseer('~\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application'))`, right?

Comment: @Tadeck, exactly. I'm currently not on Windows so somebody else will have to check, but that is how I do it on Linux.

Comment: I am also not on Windows now, so I would be happy to see it confirmed :) For now I assume it is how it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can get path with "`Ryan`" replaced by the current user's name using the following code:

```
import getpass
path_tpl = 'C:\users\{}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application'
path = path_tpl.format(getpass.getuser())
```

But you should probably base your implementation on the data you retrieve from Windows' registry - it is more reliable and the above path will work only on Windows anyways...